# https://wiki.ubuntu.com 's fonts are too small, how do I report the problem?

Tags: fonts

https://wiki.ubuntu.com page is beautiful. 
But it is too wide , this makes fonts too small.
If I enlarge page I must pull to right. It is so boring.
The font looks small especially in notebook.
This will do harm to my neck.

Can administrator revise the site style ?
I do not know if the question should be posted here.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wiki page content is maintained by the ubuntu-docs team. You can file a bug on the wiki by filing it here:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+filebug

I am not sure if the team can fix the CSS directly, so they might move it around and assign it to another team, but at least the issue will be reported.

Answer (score 1):

Change the default font size in your web browser.